# How to enumurate values from a list and then sum in a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that uses the value and the index of the value, starting from 1 to put the values in a function and sums the whole list.

In other words I'm trying to get the present value of a list of cashflows that are not the same, therefor have to calculate the present value of each cash flow and sum them.

This is what I have tried.

```
cash = [10,10,10,10, 10, 10, 11, 10]
DiscoutRate = 0.12
    for (period, value) in enumerate(cash, start=1):
        PV = value/((1+DiscountRate)**period)
        print(PV)
```

But I see that the results are not correct, any thoughts?

Comment: if u want to sum all values in list the function is sum(). sum(cash). You should probably change your question's title.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Given these cash flows and discount rate I expect an output of 50,12874688

Comment: You are supposed to add them together PV += value/((1+DiscountRate)**period)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that this solution uses a [Generator Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

```
>>> sum(value/((1 + DiscountRate) ** period) for period, value in enumerate(cash, start=1))
50.1287
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use python's map function for comprehensiveness.

```
cash = [10,10,10,10, 10, 10, 11, 10]

def get_pv(ele):
    discount_rate = 0.12
    period, value = ele

    return value / ( (1+discount_rate) ** period )

out = list(map(get_pv, enumerate(cash, start=1)))
print(sum(out))
```